# IPv6 Protocol failure

Tags: ipv6, network-protocols

I am having a weird issue with IPv6 in my Windows Server 2019 Domain Controller.

I was trying to configure IPv6 for the domain, I've typed some commands as below, when I restarted the server it doesn't have IPv6 addresses anymore, despite the IPv6 protocol is selected in the network adapter setting but there is no IPv6 IPs when I type ipconfig/ all.

Commands that I typed

```
# Use 0x20 to prefer IPv4 over IPv6 by changing entries in the prefix policy table. 
Write-Host "Modifying IPv6 bindings to prefer IPv4 over IPv6..."
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters' -Name 'DisabledComponents' -PropertyType DWORD -Value '20' -Force | Out-Null

Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias ethernet -AddressFamily IPv6 -Advertising Enabled -AdvertiseDefaultRoute Enabled
Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias ethernet -AddressFamily IPv6 -Advertising Enabled -forwarding Enabled

Set-NetIPv6Protocol -RandomizeIdentifiers Disabled
Set-NetIPv6Protocol -UseTemporaryAddresses Disabled

netsh interface ipv6 add route 2001:a0a:501:4::/64 ethernet publish=yes

netsh interface ipv6 isatap set router 10.10.5.1
netsh interface ipv6 set interface ethernet forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled
netsh interface ipv6 add route 2001:a0a:501:4::/64 ethernet publish=yes

Netsh interface ipv6 add address ethernet 2001:db8:1:1::10
```

Even when I try to assign a static IP Address in the GUT it doesn't take it, and by command line it always says element not found.

The IPv6 Protocol is not working at all.

I tried all the solutions in this website but none didn't work https://blog.pcrisk.com/windows/12839-ipv6-connectivity-no-internet-access

I ran scf /scan now and there are no issues.

Tried many things and nothing is working, IPv6 protocol vanished on the server!

can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you have tried to configure ISATAP. This should be disabled in any reasonable setup.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael for your comment, may I know why ISATAP should be disabled?

Comment: It's an obsolete transition technology that was deprecated something like 15 years ago. Having it enabled can interfere with native IPv6 connections.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the issue with issuing the command and restarting the server

```
netsh interface ipv6 reset
```

Thanks a lot